# two-dimension array after fgets?

Tags: php, arrays, function, fgets

I´m learning to work with files in php, first i made this function for writing to the file, it´s quite simple:

```
function zapis_do_suboru($zapisovany_subor, $obsah_suboru)
{
    $pracovny_subor = fopen($zapisovany_subor,"w") or die("Chyba pri otvarani suboru");
    fwrite($pracovny_subor, $obsah_suboru) or die("Nejde zapisovat do suboru");
    fclose($pracovny_subor);
    echo "Zapis $zapisovany_subor prebehol uspesne.";
}
```

Then I made function for reading from the file, but I was little stuck here, because my book is explaining how to read just one row, but then i googled little bit and found some solution and made this function for reading from file:

```
function citanie_zo_suboru($citany_subor)
{
    $pracovny_subor = fopen($citany_subor,"r") or die("Chyba pri otvarani suboru");
    $j = 0;
    while(!feof($pracovny_subor))
        {
        $pole[$j] = array(fgets($pracovny_subor, 4096));
        $j++;    
        }

    fclose($pracovny_subor);
    return $pole;   
}
```

Then i wanted to test it, so i create two variables:

```
$subor = "textsubor.txt";
$text = <<<_END
Riadok1 blabla
Riadok2 blabla
Riadok3 meno suboru: $subor 
_END;
```

And this calling of functions:

```
zapis_do_suboru($subor, $text);
echo "<br />";
foreach (citanie_zo_suboru($subor) as $index =>$popis)
    echo $popis."<br />";
```

But the problem is, that function citanie_zo_suboru is creating two-dimension array, so the output was only "array array array array". With print_r and little bit of trying i found out, that when i change:

```
foreach (citanie_zo_suboru($subor) as $index =>$popis)
    echo $popis."<br />";
```

to:

```
foreach (citanie_zo_suboru($subor) as $index =>$popis)
    echo $popis[0]."<br />";
```

it's doing exactly what i wanted. Can someone tell me why my function is creating two-dimension and not just classic one-dimension array? I would be really grateful if you could. Thanks

Comment: looks to me like $pole[$j] = array(fgets($pracovny_subor, 4096)); should be $pole[$j] = fgets($pracovny_subor, 4096);

Comment: @JoeMinichino ou thanks it really works, now i get it what i did wrong :) thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing array in array key:

```
$pole[$j] = array(fgets($pracovny_subor, 4096));
```

So, $pole[0] should further contain array.

Comment: Yes, I see and with comment from @JoeMinichino it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To simply write a file you can use `file_put_contens()` : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php

To read a file you have the same `file_get_contents()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

To read a file and store each line as value in an array use `file()` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

I hope this 3 function can help you in your current issue.

Comment: Yes, I know about those function but i wanted to made it with my function. But thanks :)